# ???? How does one make contact with domain result of: RDDS service of the Registrar of Record

Tags: registrar

I am trying to locate owner of domain:  LinkedInPro.CO   I have reviewed WHOIS and it states REDACTED FOR PRIVACY.  Further, Admin Email: Please query the RDDS service of the Registrar of Record identified in this output for information on how to contact the Registrant.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: the same question has already been asked [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1366161/what-is-rdds-service-and-how-to-query-the-rdds-service) :)

Comment: You don't. That's the whole point of the privacy service. If you need to contact the registrant then you either go through the privacy service or you see if there is some kind of "contact us" form on the site itself.

Comment: The owner of the business is [National Résumé Writers' Association - Member public profile](https://thenrwa.com/Sys/PublicProfile/48772409/3660697)

Comment: She has Facebook, LinkedIn and Twitter accounts and an email address. Plenty of  ways to contact her.